# Получить значение свойства

Tags: javascript

Добавь объекту atTheOldToad метод getPotions(), который просто возвращает значение свойства potions.Значение свойства atTheOldToad.getPotions это метод объекта
Вызов метода atTheOldToad.getPotions() возвращает ['Speed potion', 'Dragon breath', 'Stone skin']
Задания

```
const atTheOldToad = {
  // Change code below this line
  potions: ['Speed potion', 'Dragon breath', 'Stone skin'],
  // Change code above this line
};
```

Мой метод (не совсем понял суть задания)

```
const atTheOldToad = {
  // Change code below this line
  potions: ['Speed potion', 'Dragon breath', 'Stone skin'],
  getPotions = [...potions]
  // Change code above this line
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const atTheOldToad = {
  // Change code below this line
  potions: ['Speed potion', 'Dragon breath', 'Stone skin'],
  getPotions() { 
    return this.potions;
  }
  // Change code above this line
}; 

console.log(atTheOldToad.getPotions())
```